# Composer: where should I put the "vendor" folder?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, composer-php, amazon-ses

I have concerns that are similar to what were addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23579984/security-should-i-move-vendor-dir-and-composer-json-outside-of-document-root). I'm using Composer to install Amazon AWS components to set up a SES (email) service.

According to the Amazon [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/guide/latest/installation.html), I need to include `autoload.php` in order to use the classes that I installed. This means that the `autoload.php` must be in my web directory (/var/www/html).

I didn't fully understand the answer provided to the SO question I previous mentioned, but it essentially says that the vendor directory should NOT be in the web directory. But if I do this, how will I `require` the `autoload.php` file, which is in the /vendor directory?

Overall I am very confused about how I should be properly setting this up. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit:** [This](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-composer-on-your-vps-running-ubuntu) article also suggests putting the /vendor/ folder in the web directory. Is this the standard? What security risks should I be looking out for? Because there are no index.html files or anything in any of the folders, the directories of all the files that were installed can be seen and accessed freely. Surely this can't be a good thing?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The "web directory" is the directory directly served via HTTP to anyone asking with the right URL. So if anyone thinks there is a folder "/foo" hosted on your domain, and you didn't take precautions, and there is in fact that folder, and it does not contain a file that would be served as the directory index, anyone asking probably would get the directory listing of that folder, listing all files.

Now the difference between such a web hosted folder and the `require` statement in PHP is that PHP does not use a URL pointing at a publicly accessible HTTP hosted folder, but uses a filesystem path pointing to a file.

And most beginners mix this up: Because PHP at starter level is all about having a bunch of scripts spread around the web directory, which emit a lot of HTML containing links to other scripts, they get the idea that the links in HTML and the file paths in PHP are the same and have to be. This is wrong. They don't have to be the same, they are the same because no better approach has been selected.

So here's how a modern web application is constructed. If you deploy the whole project, the main directory on the server might be called `/var/www/projectX`. Inside this container are some files like `/var/www/projectX/composer.json`. Because of this there will also be a directory `/var/www/projectX/vendor`. Additionally, somewhere would be one PHP script that's being accessed (I delay the info HOW it's being accessed for now), and that location should either be A) `/var/www/projectX/script.php` or B) `/var/www/projectX/public/script.php`. Those two scripts want to use Composer provided classes and need to include the autoloading.

Because of the file location, the script in location A needs to run `require 'vendor/autoload.php';`, and the script in location B needs `require '../vendor/autoload.php';`. This is simply a matter of using the correct relative path from the script to the autoload file. You could even use an absolute path in both cases: `require '/var/www/projectX/vendor/autoload.php';` will also work. The main point here is: It does not matter HOW you require that autoload.php file as long as it gets executed by the script. The path does not affect anything.

Now the HTTP hosting and accessing the scripts. The webserver has at least one directory configured that is being exposed to the outside world as the main directory of the domain. This is called `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, and it can be ANYWHERE. Now it depends on the configuration of your server which directory is preselected, and if you can change that setting (either by administrating your server on the command line, or by clicking some settings in a GUI).

If your server has the directory `/var/www/projectX` set as the document root, all the world can access the script in case A as `http://example.com/script.php`, as well as the script in case B as `http://example.com/public/script.php`, and also the vendor folder as `http://example.com/vendor/...`. This is not great, but could be avoided by placing `.htaccess` files inside or otherwise restrict access.

The better solution is to tell the server to only serve the directory `/var/www/projectX/public` as document root. This will prevent HTTP access to script A and the vendor folder, and access to script B is done via `http://example.com/script.php`.

In both cases, both scripts successfully include the autoloading of Composer because the restrictions of HTTP access do not apply to filesystem access.

Bad website hosting allows you only to use the first scenario, with the only accessible directory for you being directly the document root, without a method to change it.

More sophisticated website hosting ís using a fixed subdirectory like `public` or `html` or `webroot` as the document root, allowing you to hide sensitive files from ever being served via HTTP.

The best website hosting allows you to select which subdirectory should be hosted as document root.

In any case, the path pointing from a script to Composers autoload.php is not affected at all.

Comment: Thanks for explaining, I think I understand better now. My web directory root is in `/var/www/html/`, so in this situation its advisable to put the `vendor` folder somewhere like `/var/www/vendor` and then access it via relative pathing, is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. Note however that you are not free to put that folder anywhere you like by selectively uploading it via FTP. That folder gets created because your Composer configuration put's it somewhere, and your own classes should also be included in that autoloading as well. So all you are supposed to do is create the directory structure as intended on your development machine, run Composer (and anything else), and then simply upload the whole structure in one go to the server.